# Trying to get nested exception from exception.cause

Tags: java, exception, kotlin

I have a try-catch block as follows:

```
try {

  code that may throw an exception

} catch (e: DataIntegrityException) {

  val cause = e.cause

  //prints "Is the cause a ConstraintViolationException: false"
  println("Is the cause a ConstraintViolationException: " (cause is ConstraintViolationException))

  //prints org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
  println(cause)

  //Here I want to do something with a ConstraintViolationException.

}
```

The DataIntegrityException that I catch has a nested ConstraintViolationException that I need to have to use `cause.constraintViolations`.

I have tried catching the ConstraintViolationException directly but since it's within the DataIntegrityViolation the catch isn't triggered.

I'm quite confused why `(cause is ConstraintViolationException)` evaluates to `false` when the `println(cause)` suggests that it is a ConstraintViolationException?

Comment: Could it be that you have a wrong import statement in place? Note that there also exists a [`javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html)...

Comment: Yes! Thanks, there are two imports with the same name